# Why console.log is returning different value than alert?

Tags: javascript, css

console.log and alert returning different values. Code is regarding to find Computed Style of `left` property.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const smallDevice = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1490px)");
  smallDevice.addListener(handleDeviceChange);

  function handleDeviceChange(e) {
    if (e.matches) {
      const left = $(".sidebar").css("left");
      alert(left);
      console.log(left);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@media (max-width: 1490px) {
  .sidebar2 {
    right: -300px !important;
  }
  .sidebar {
    left: -300px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
  <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">
        <img class="logo" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR3pZ-gZavZ--zmy5TluKQHw-5aKDXYlrnnbQ&usqp=CAU" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">
        <i class="bi- bi-calendar-event "></i>
        <span>الأحداث</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">
        <i class="bi- bi-newspaper "></i>
        <span>الأخبار</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</aside>

<aside class="sidebar2" id="sidebar2">
  <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">
        <img class="logo" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR3pZ-gZavZ--zmy5TluKQHw-5aKDXYlrnnbQ&usqp=CAU" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">
        <i class="bi- bi-calendar-event "></i>
        <span>الأحداث</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">
        <i class="bi- bi-newspaper "></i>
        <span>الأخبار</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: Use addEventListener() instead of addListener(). Also add fiddle to identify your issue.

Comment: @DhruvangGajjar what will be the event name if I use addEventListener

Comment: What is addListener(...) and what is css(...)? Are you using jquery? What does your browser's devtools inspect facility tell you in the console? Please put a runnable snippet into your question (NOT on an external site) see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @user123456 depend on your requirement.. may be load and resize would be the event.

Comment: @DhruvangGajjar I think your answer works and is useful as it gives a workaround but it does not answer the original question which is 'Why' do alert and the console give different results.

Comment: @AHaworth Right but I tried running above code which it doesn't give any alert or console.

Comment: Please make your code into a proper runnable snippet (mend the @@ typo and remember to load jquery). Then test it and make sure it shows the issue - it has changed since your original question and I cannot make it give the problem now.

Comment: @DhruvangGajjar you are maybe getting nothing from running the code in the question as it currently stands because it has an error in the CSS (@@) and/or you haven't loaded jquery.

Comment: The initial question and the updated code aren't really similar. In the first case what you called `console.log` was actually you typing in the console. There it could very well be that the value was not yet updated when the `alert` fired, but got updated when you typed in the console. With the updated code, there is  absolutely no reason that you get different results, (since the value is a string), unless you modified either `console.log` or `alert`, that is. Are you sure that with the provided code you experience what you say you experience?

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is mostly correct, but you are using id selector instead of class selector.

Also, you need to use `e.matches` instead of `smallDevice.matches`.

This code works fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    const smallDevice = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1490px)");
    smallDevice.addListener(handleDeviceChange);
    function handleDeviceChange(e) {
      if (e.matches) {
        const left = $(".sidebar").css("left");
        console.log(left);
        alert(left);
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
@media (max-width: 1490px) {
  .sidebar2 {
    right: -300px !important;
  }

  .sidebar {
    left: -300px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="sidebar2"></div>
```

Comment: I am stilll getting 0 as result not -300

Comment: Did you run code snippet in full page mode?

Comment: yes I did  my firend

Comment: what about the result? I make sure that it's correct.

Comment: still getting 0 px not -300

Comment: oh, please share your whole code. (please update question)

Comment: hi, friend. your media query is incorrect. please rewrite `@media` instead of `@@media`

Comment: it is ,net coire page

Comment: Umm, that's weird. please change order of `console.log` and `alert`. and then please check values. I mean first is `log` and second is `alert`.

Comment: it worked with this code const smallDevice = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1490px)");
window.addEventListener('resize', handleDeviceChange)
window.addEventListener('load', handleDeviceChange)

function handleDeviceChange(e) {
  if (smallDevice.matches) {
    const left = $(".sidebar").css("left");
    console.log(left);
    alert(left)
  }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254489/discussion-between-victor-l-and-user123456).

Comment: `e.matches` is supposed to be the same as the `target`'s  `.matches`, (unless you read it after a future event)

Comment: I see, but this code works fine in HTML but OP's code is using .net core. what difference between them? I can't understand.

Comment: Yes I don't understand either. Clearly there is something off with this question either in the description of the issue or in the provided code, or some missing information about their environment, or a bit of all these, but we don't have enough to possibly answer it.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience with me. I have learned a lot from you.

Answer (score 0):

With addEventListener, It returns the same values in alert and console.log

```js
const smallDevice = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1490px)");

smallDevice.addEventListener("change", handleDeviceChange);

function handleDeviceChange(e) {
  if (e.matches) {
    const el = document.querySelector(".sidebar")
    const left = getComputedStyle(el)['left']
    console.log(left);
    alert(left)
  }
}
```

```css
@media (max-width: 1490px) {
  .sidebar2 {
    right: -300px !important;
  }
  .sidebar {
    left: -300px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="sidebar2"></div>
```

Comment: This will fire MANY times for no good reasons.

Comment: Yes, But specific requirement is not available. If resize event is not required, can remove it.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment. The MediaQueryList API has features that do match exactly what OP is willing to achieve. They are using a slightly outdated version of it, but what they do ought to work anyway. Your answer is not using the correct API. It is using a very bad workaround instead for no good reasons since there is a proper API.

Comment: @Kaiido I get your point. I wasn't aware of MediaQueryList API. I have updated answer and used MediaQueryList

Comment: Just as OP is doing. `MediaQueryList#addListener`  is supposed to be a wrapper over `MediaQueryList#addEventListener` and they're both supposed to work the same. So while, yes, it works with `MediaQueryList#addEventListener` it also does work with `MediaQueryList#addListener` like OP is doing.